# Conditional Formatting a Row based on a Cell value using VAB

Tags: excel, formatting, excel-2003, vba

I am working on a speadsheet that takes the tasks that everyone is doing and pioritises them and i am having difficalty formatting the rows as word 2003 only lets you do three formats and i ahve alreday used them up!  I would like to format the rows like so;

If the number in cell C## is 1 the Row tuns Red, if its 2 it turns orange, if it is 3 it turns yellow, if its 4 it turns light green and if its 5 it turns dark green.

Also if cell F## is Yes then the colour of the righing goes gray and the writing is crossed out.

Finally if the date in cell D## is overdue then the whole rows writting goes BOLD.

I know it can be done easily on excel 2010 but we havent upgraded yet at work.

Can awayone help?

Thanks.

Comment: introduce yourself to VBA and use `if then` statements <- that should be your starting point

Answer (score 0):

here is a quick start you can elaborate on;

type ALT+F11; the VBA editor will appear, locate your sheet in the left side panel (if panel is not there type CTRL+R) double click your sheet and its module will show in the right panel

copy and paste the following code:

```
Sub update_color_codes()


    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    numrow = Selection.Rows.Count

    For r = 1 To numrow

    c = Cells(r, 3).Value

    Select Case c

           Case 1
           pickedcolor = RGB(0, 255, 0)
           Case 2
           pickedcolor = RGB(0, 125, 0)
           Case 3
           pickedcolor = RGB(255, 255, 0)
           Case 4
           pickedcolor = RGB(125, 125, 0)
           Case 5
           pickedcolor = RGB(255, 0, 0)


    End Select 'c


    With Range(Cells(r, 1), Cells(r, 6)).Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .Color = pickedcolor
    End With



    Next 'r = 1 To numrow



End Sub
```

To run this macros, type ALT+F8, select it in the list and click RUN.

to ease the process, create a keyboard shortcut like this:
type ALT+F8, select it in the list and click OPTIONS, enter your shortcut key (i recommend something that will not interfere with default shortcut such as CTRL+SHIFT+U)

assumption is made your list starts on A1 and has 6 columns, correct as needed; the number of rows is found out at the beginning by the macro;

play with the RGB values until satisfied and 
explore VBA to adjust this code to control font weight etc.

hope that help